# How can I patch "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages"

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I try to clone and install this repository 
[OCPlatform](https://github.com/winzou/OCPlatform) I have create a database named symfoni and renamed the file parameters.yml and update like this:

```
parameters:
database_driver:   pdo_mysql
database_host:     127.0.0.1
database_port:     ~
database_name:     symfoni
database_user:     symfoni
database_password: symfoni

mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_host:       127.0.0.1
mailer_user:       ~
mailer_password:   ~

locale:            en
secret:            ThisIsAChangedSecret

debug_toolbar:          true
debug_redirects:        false
use_assetic_controller: true
```

but when I try the command line

```
> php composer.phar install
```

, when I use this command this one generate an error:

```
    Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for symfony/icu v1.2.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.2].
    - symfony/icu v1.2.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - symfony/icu v1.2.2 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
    - symfony/symfony v2.5.3 requires symfony/icu ~1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.2].
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony v2.5.3 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.5.3].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

How can I patch this error ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

it requires php extension `intl` **the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.**

try to install it and restart services (php, apache..):

```
#for centos, rhel
yum install php-intl

#for debian, ubuntu
apt-get install php-intl
```

Comment: I have use the command `brew install homebrew/php/php56-intl` and restart services but nothing change, I have the same error.

Comment: check php.ini if this extension is enabled `extension=intl.so` or `php -m | grep intl`

Comment: I don't have `extension=intl.so` in my php.ini but I have a comment with `extension=php_intl.dll`

Comment: try to add `extension=intl.so` to php.ini and restart apache. `extension=php_intl.dll` - it is for windows.

Comment: `php -m | grep intl` outputs line `intl`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138824/discussion-between-dutycorpse-and-max-p).